# Change heading style: Italicize words (in heading title) without italicizing heading number

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I want my headings to appear as such

1.1 *History of the Universe*

[Body]

1.2 *History of the Milky Way*

[Body]

where the heading numbers "1.1" and "1.2" are not italicized, but the heading titles "History of the Universe" and "History of the Milky Way" are.

How do I change the heading style so that this works whenever I summon this particular heading style/level? Right now I'm only able to do it so that either both the number and the title are italicized or neither is.

Answer (score 1):

In an automatically numbered list, the properties of the list are stored separately from the properties of the paragraph.

Assuming you are using a multilevel list based on Heading styles for your paragraph numbering, select one of the headings, then
click the dropdown at the right hand side of the multilevel list icon in the Home tab (it's the third of three bullet/numbering icons), then click "Define new multilevel list..."

You should then see the list of Headings and the correct numbering for each level of your list. For each level whose formatting you want to modify,

- Select the level
- Click the Font... button
- Apply the formatting you want

That should modify the formatting for the current document. I would do some thorough testing before committing to this approach (I say this because Word's numbered list stuff has never been easy to get right).

If you want to start with that formatting when you create new documents, you can create a template and base new documents on that template, or open and modify the Normal template. IN either case, you would need to insert some headings, apply the list format, and go through the same steps as above, then remove the headings and save the template.

FWIW my Normal template is at

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\

where "username" is my user name, but yours may be ina different location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that version of MS Word, so I can't check out this option.

In earlier versions of Word (pre 2000), the paragraph character at the end of the line would determine the font characteristics of the numbers. To select the paragraph character, go to the end of the line (press ), hold down the shift key and press the right arrow. Change the selection to the desired format.

Comment: Yes right now what I do is (1) add a junk character at the end of the heading title and leave it unitalicized; (2) italicize all characters before that last character; and (3) delete that last junk character. But what I'm looking for is a way to change the heading style permanently so I don't have to do this every time.